# convert C# httpwebrequest to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, download, header, httpwebrequest

i have this C# code for download xlsx document from url

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url to xlsx file");
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip,deflate";
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var output = File.Create("H:\\doc.xlsx"))
            {
                stream.CopyTo(output);
            }
```

my target programming language is VB.net so i changed C# to vb like below

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("url to xlsx file")
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        request.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding) = "gzip,deflate"
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim output As FileStream = File.Create("H:\doc.xlsx")

        stream.CopyTo(output)
```

xlsx file that is downloaded by VB is corrupted and unreadable but C# works well
what is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the `using` statements: It is possible the whole content has not been flushed to the output so you get the corrupt message.

```
Using response = request.GetResponse()
    Using stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Using output = File.Create("H:\doc.xlsx")
            stream.CopyTo(output)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

The `using` block will make sure to dispose of the objects, which you should be doing regardless of the issue of ending with a corrupted file, and it will also call `Close()` method on the underlying to stream and any data previously written to the buffer will be copied to the file before the file stream is closed,